# mysql LIKE match, but need to filter by username

Tags: php, mysql

I have several users that have items. I need each user to be able to search their items, and not see other people items's. This query still allows the executer to see every item in the dbase. Please help!

$findit is a variable earlier in the script that is what the user is looking for. 
$username is set via a session cookie after they login.

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM prices WHERE 
            itemnum LIKE '%$findit%' ||
            itemdesc LIKE '%$findit%' AND username = '$username' ORDER BY price");
```

Comment: BTW you should use OR instead of || in SQL.

Comment: AND has higher precedence then OR in most languages...including SQL. Edit: I wasn't clear. I meant the same "predecence priority/order"

Comment: @gbn No, see the chart linked below. (or here again: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html)

Comment: @Shi: I've fixed my comment. I didn't phrase it well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to group the OR:

```
SELECT * 
FROM prices 
WHERE (itemnum LIKE '%$findit%'
   OR  itemdesc LIKE '%$findit%')
  AND username = '$username'
ORDER BY price
```

Which will make the OR act as a single condition, and the username match as another, so that the username is required to be matched.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM prices WHERE 
        (itemnum LIKE '%$findit%' OR itemdesc LIKE '%$findit%')
        AND username = '$username' ORDER BY price");
```

notice the parentheses. If they aren't there, it'll match either `itemnum LIKE ...` *or* `itemdesc LIKE ... and username = ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM prices WHERE 
        (itemnum LIKE '%$findit%' ||
        itemdesc LIKE '%$findit%') AND username = '$username' ORDER BY price");
```

The brackets are missing. `AND` has a higher [operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) than `OR`.